# Do facebook popup login and open link in new tab

Tags: facebook

I have a link such as:

```
<a href="/somepage" target="_blank">Go there</a>
```

I also have a click listener on this link which calls `FB.login()`

The result, in Chrome, is that the FB login dialog is shown as a popup but the link to /somepage in a new tab is blocked by Chrome, saying that it's a blocked popup

Is there a way to let the page open in a new tab, and have the FB login dialog appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This operation is not possible in Chrome. suffer popup blocker. or open link in current window

set anchor's attribute **target="_self"**

```
`<a href="/somepage" target="_self">Go there</a>`
```